# The $bucket 'boundaries' field must be an array, but found type: string

Tags: laravel, mongodb, aggregation-framework

need to pass `$contents` as `boundaries` value but I am facing the above error. Kindly help out. Thanks in advance

```
 $contents = $query->pluck('competition_id')->toArray();

        $data = $query->raw(function ($collection) {
        return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$bucket' => [ 
                    'groupBy' => '$competition_id',
                    'boundaries' => '$contents',
                    'default' => "Other",
                    'output' => [
                        "data" => [
                            '$push' => [
                                "id"                => '$id',
                                "season_id"         => '$season_id',
                                "status_id"         => '$status_id',
                                "venue_id"          => '$venue_id',
                                "referee_id"        =>  '$referee_id',
                                "neutral"           => '$neutral',
                    

                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> `'boundaries' => '$contents'`
>
> *The `$bucket` 'boundaries' field must be an array, but found type: string*

The `$bucket` boundaries can't allow internal fields by reference, it will consider as string and it requires input as array from external,

It must be an external array elements as provided instruction in [$bucket documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/#syntax),

> *An array of values based on the groupBy expression that specify the boundaries for each bucket. Each adjacent pair of values acts as the inclusive lower boundary and the exclusive upper boundary for the bucket. You must specify at least two boundaries.*
>
> *The specified values must be in ascending order and all of the same type. The exception is if the values are of mixed numeric types, such as:*
>
> [ 10, NumberLong(20), NumberInt(30) ]
>
> **EXAMPLE:**
>
> - *An array of [ 0, 5, 10 ] creates two buckets:*
>
>   - [0, 5) with inclusive lower bound 0 and exclusive upper bound 5.
>   - [5, 10) with inclusive lower bound 5 and exclusive upper bound 10.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to sort this out i need to pass the boundaries value dynamically it can't be static. Thanks

Comment: no it is not possible using $bucket, but you can ask new question with exact requirement like example document and expected result, might be there will be other approach to achieve your requirement.

Comment: okay thanks. I have posted a new question i want to groupby using $group in mongodb and fetch all values from collection. kindly help to check on this. Thanks. I have added the link to the question as well

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463860/groupby-in-mongodb-and-fetch-all-the-values-from-the-collection)