# GroupBy in mongodb and fetch all the values from the collection

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, aggregation-framework

this is the sample data.Need to groupby competition_id. Need all data from the collection after group by. I have added sample collections and the required output ss. Kindly help to check. Thanks in advance.

```
{
    "id": "l5ergph87pgdr8k",
    "season_id": "",
    "status_id": 13,
    "venue_id": "",
    "referee_id": "",
    "neutral": 0,
    "note": "",
    "home_scores": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "away_scores": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "home_position": "",
    "away_position": "",
    "coverage": {
        "mlive": 0,
        "lineup": 0
    },
    "round": {
        "stage_id": "",
        "round_num": 0,
        "group_num": 0
    },
    "updated_at": "2021-05-01 18:47:55",
    "competition_id": "kjw2r09hx9drz84",
    "competition_name": "Australia Gold Coast Reserves",
    "home_team_id": "3glrw7h1d2oqdyj",
    "home_team_name": "Palm Beach Reserves",
    "away_team_id": "n54qllh8941qvy9",
    "away_team_name": "Nerang B Reserves",
    "match_time": "2021-05-01 13:45:00",
    "match_tsp": 1619847900,
    "created_at": "2021-05-04 14:33:10"
}
```

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
    "id": "jw2r09h0g0p3rz8",
    "season_id": "",
    "status_id": 1,
    "venue_id": "",
    "referee_id": "",
    "neutral": 0,
    "note": "",
    "home_scores": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "away_scores": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "home_position": "",
    "away_position": "",
    "coverage": {
        "mlive": 0,
        "lineup": 0
    },
    "round": {
        "stage_id": "",
        "round_num": 0,
        "group_num": 0
    },
    "updated_at": "2021-05-06 12:18:52",
    "competition_id": "vl7oqdeh0vxr510",
    "competition_name": "Faroe Islands Division 1",
    "home_team_id": "dj2ryohjvezq1zp",
    "home_team_name": "Vikingur Gota II",
    "away_team_id": "jw2r09hxgzjrz84",
    "away_team_name": "B36 Torshavn II",
    "match_time": "2021-05-08 01:00:00",
    "match_tsp": 1620406800,
    "created_at": "2021-05-06 12:20:11"
}
```

Expected output

[image]

Thank you. If there is anything else required can let me know thanks

Comment: your question is not clear can you elaborate more and post 2/3 documents and expected result from that documents.

Comment: hi, i have done this process using mapReduce concept in mongodb but not sure how to replicate that in laravel framework.Need your help to check on that. I have shared the link below [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67464996/how-to-write-the-below-mapreduce-mongodb-query-in-laravel-framework)

Comment: i don't know more about php mongodb syntax, someone will help you.

Comment: i have added sample documents and required output screenshots i have edited the question . You may have a look and see. Thanks

Comment: @turivishal i have added sample documents and required output screenshots i have edited the question . You may have a look and see. Thanks

Comment: still your question is not clear, the statement *Need to groupby competition_id* and your expected result does not match. need more details

Comment: @turivishal at this stage i don't have any sample output available i just need to groupby competition_id  and after grouping i need the whole collection in the result in mongodb after groupby i am just getting the unique id alone. Are you able to get me ?

Comment: see [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator docs. and see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RsVRaK1nsP0) you can add fields like `competition_name` that i have added in playground.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to groupby a particular value in mongodb using laravel and need to fetch all values from the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458880/how-to-groupby-a-particular-value-in-mongodb-using-laravel-and-need-to-fetch-all)