# The $bucket 'default' field must be less than the lowest boundary or greater than or equal to the highest boundary

Tags: laravel, mongodb, aggregation-framework

What does this bug refer to? I have pasted the code below. Kindly have a look. Can anyone let me know what's wrong with the boundary value here? Thanks in advance

```
    db.match_list.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $bucket: {
                groupBy: "$competition_id",                      
                boundaries: ["9dn1m1gh41emoep","9dn1m1ghew6moep", "d23xmvkh4g8qg8n","gy0or5jhj6qwzv3"], 
                default: "Other",                             
                output: {                                    
                    "data" : {
                        $push: {
                           "season_id": "$season_id",
                            "status_id": "$status_id",
                            "venue_id": "$venue_id",
                            "referee_id": "$referee_id",
                            "neutral":"$neutral",
                            "note": "$note",
                            "home_scores":"$home_scores",
                            "away_scores": "$away_scores",
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort : { competition_id : 1 }
        },
    ])
```

mongodb laravel query using raw. Not sure what's going wrong here.new_array vale also has been mentioned

```
 $contents = $query->orderby('competition_id')->pluck('competition_id')->toArray();
        $contents = array_unique($contents);
        $new_array = array_values($contents); 

$data = $query->raw(function ($collection) use ($new_array) {
            return $collection->aggregate([
                [
                    
                    '$bucket' => [ 
                        'groupBy' => '$competition_id',
                        'boundaries' => $new_array,
                        'default' => 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz',
                        'output' => [
                            "data" => [
                                '$push' => [
                                    "id"                => '$id',
                                    "season_id"         => '$season_id',
                                    "status_id"         => '$status_id',
                                    "venue_id"          => '$venue_id',
                                    "referee_id"        =>  '$referee_id',
                                    "neutral"           => '$neutral',
                                    "note"              => '$note',
                                    "home_scores"       => '$home_scores',
                                                                    
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                 ]
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: You don't show any input nor output data, I assume `{$group: { _id: "$competition_id"}, count: {$sum: 1} }` might be sufficient.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit , i have added the input and output sample data in a separate question this is the link for that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463860/groupby-in-mongodb-and-fetch-all-the-values-from-the-collection).... kindly help to check on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have entered `Other` in the `default` parameter of the `$bucket` parameter which
is in between the `min-max` boundaries you have provided.

I would suggest you try a value of the greater or lesser string than to that provided in the
`boundaries` array or better enter a different datatype value such as int of `1`.

```
db.match_list.aggregate( [
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$competition_id",                      
      boundaries: ["9dn1m1gh41emoep","9dn1m1ghew6moep", "d23xmvkh4g8qg8n","gy0or5jhj6qwzv3"], 
      default: 1,  // Or `zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz` (any greater or lesser value than provided in `boundaries`
      output: {                                    
        "data" :
          {
            $push: {
              "season_id": "$season_id",
              "status_id": "$status_id",
              "venue_id": "$venue_id",
              "referee_id": "$referee_id",
              "neutral":"$neutral",
              "note": "$note",
              "home_scores":"$home_scores",
              "away_scores": "$away_scores",
            }
          }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort : { competition_id : 1 } },
] )
```

Comment: Thanks that worked now i am trying to replicate the same in laravel raw() function but my output is wrong and is not as expected i have added that code in the question for your reference.kindly help out. Thanks

Comment: no error but the result is wrong. i have posted this as another question can you help to check on that, i have posted the link as well [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463860/groupby-in-mongodb-and-fetch-all-the-values-from-the-collection) . kindly help to check on this

Comment: share the sample input and result you are getting